# % of full nodes running Bitcoin Core versus other node software

Tags: full-node

Is anybody able to tell me a credible source (for an article) that can show me the percentage of all bitcoin full nodes that are running Bitcoin Core (as opposed to other software)?

I could not find this information at bitcoincore.org or at bitnodes.io.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**80836** Bitcoin Core nodes

**577** Bitcoin Knots nodes

**315** other nodes (BTCD, Libbitcoin, bcoin, gocoin etc.)

[image: nodes]

https://luke.dashjr.org/programs/bitcoin/files/charts/software.html

Comment: it's right, luke dashyr's chart has another useful count, could you mention why its stats showing many more nodes than any other and why it's the only one that show this "extended stats"?

Comment: Only Luke Dashjr can share more information about it and answer related questions. Someone had asked a question in August last year: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/98646/how-exactly-does-coindance-determine-the-current-number-of-public-bitcoin-node/98821

Comment: afaik Luke's node count is higher because he also counts nodes that don't allow inbound connections and I guess he can do it because he manages one of the few DNS seed nodes (but not sure about last one).

Answer (score -1):

[bitnodes.io](https://bitnodes.io/dashboard), in its user agents chart, show an "Other" category, but probably it will include also older versions of Bitcoin Core.
[image]

On [blockchair.com](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/nodes) you can find details of which clients are used by full nodes, but they are grouped by user agents, so you need to manually count Bitcoin Core version and other clients.

on [coin.dance](https://coin.dance/nodes) you find exactly what you looking for, but right now is in maintenance, here there is a snapshot from archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20210124183839/https://coin.dance/nodes

[image]

Comment: These sites only show listening nodes.

Comment: how can we count nodes that do not listen?